# MPAndroidChart live data not visible without initial bounds

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have to display realtime data in the app. I chose MPAndroidChart as a library for charts.

But without settings initial dataset with entries or setting axis minimum and axis maximum (x axis) my chart isn't displayed (with this settings I can't scroll chart). I almost already copied all code from the example, but it's still invisible (example starts without bounds of x axis and works good):

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/RealtimeLineChartActivity.java

Here is example with fixed max/min X[image: Max min fixed chart]

Here is example of bug, no data shown: [image: No data]

Everything is inside the fragment in the viewpager:

Here is code of the initing line chart:

```
line_chart.apply {

      description.apply {
        isEnabled = true
        text = "Live chart"
      }

      setTouchEnabled(true)

      isDragEnabled = true
      setScaleEnabled(true)
      setDrawGridBackground(false)

      setPinchZoom(true)


      data = LineData().apply {
        setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK)
      }

      // THIS:
//      data = LineData(dataset("Simple").apply {
//        for (i in 1..10) {
//          addEntry(Entry(i.toFloat(), i.toFloat()))
//        }
//      })

      legend.apply {
        form = LINE
        textColor = Color.BLACK
      }

      xAxis.apply {
        textColor = Color.BLACK
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
        isEnabled = true
        granularity = 5f
        axisMinimum = 0f
        axisMaximum = 20f

        setValueFormatter { value, _ -> Date(value.toLong()).simpleSecondsFormat() }
      }

      axisLeft.apply {
        textColor = Color.BLACK

        // OR THIS:
        //axisMinimum = 0f
        //axisMaximum = 12f
        setDrawGridLines(true)
      }

      axisRight.isEnabled = false

      setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100f)
    }
```

Code for creating dataset:

```
fun dataset(label: String): LineDataSet = LineDataSet(null, label).apply {
  axisDependency = LEFT
  color = Color.BLACK
  setCircleColor(Color.RED)
  lineWidth = 2f
  circleRadius = 4f
  fillAlpha = 65
  fillColor = Color.RED
  highLightColor = Color.GREEN
  valueTextColor = Color.RED
  valueTextSize = 9f
  setDrawValues(true)
}
```

Data comes from the store, using RxJava2:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext { Timber.d("Entry: $it, timestamp: ${it.timestamp}") }
        .doOnNext {

          line_chart.data.apply {
            val dataSet = getDataSetByLabel(it.macAddress, true) ?: dataset(
                it.macAddress).also { addDataSet(it) }

            addEntry(Entry(it.timestamp.toFloat(), it.energy),
                getIndexOfDataSet(dataSet))

            notifyDataChanged()
          }
        }
        .doOnNext {
          line_chart.apply {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            setVisibleXRangeMaximum(120f)
            invalidate()
          }
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally fixed issue, by removing line `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100f)` from the first snippet.